# StrongGrid - Parse inbound email not working

Tags: sendgrid, stronggrid

I am trying to get StrongGrid working with the raw post but seem to be struggling with something simple!

This is the example code I am using on my aspx page the POST is sent too:

```
   var parser = new WebhookParser();
   var inboundEmail = parser.ParseInboundEmailWebhook(Request.InputStream);
```

When I try and get the text or HTML its empty:

```
   var myHtml = inboundEmail.Html.ToString();  
   var myText = inboundEmail.Text.ToString();
```

The other bits like from/to/cc etc are all ok - just not these.

What am I doing wrong ?

Cheers
Pete

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this question you asked several months ago but I was curious if you ever figure out the issue? If not, please post the payload posted to your aspx page (in other words, the content of the request) and I'll be happy to investigate further.

By the way, the `Html` and the `Text` properties of the `InboundEmail` class are  `string` properties. Therefore no need to invoke `ToString()` to get their content. You simply need:

```cs
var myHtml = inboundEmail.Html;  
var myText = inboundEmail.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Sendgrid doesn't send "html" and "text" fields or StrongGrid doesn't parse them when you check "POST the raw, full MIME message" in webhook.

Unchecking that field helped

Comment: at the time you posted your comment, StrongGrid did not support the "Raw, full MIME" format. As you mentioned, unchecking the "POST the raw full MIME message" option in your SendGrid options was indeed the solution that allowed StrongGrid to fully parse the inbound email webhook. However, this changed in November 2023 and StrongGrid is now able to parse the content of the webhook no matter which format you selected. Hope this helps.